# Is there a way to find the average of an item from a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, average

I have a WindowsFormsApp in C# where i get as input the First Name, Last name and the Grade of a student( as objects in a list). Every time i press a button the program should return the average of grades from all the students that i have input until now.
Here is how i created the student objects.

```
List<Student> listaStudenti = new List<Student>();
        Student objStudenti;
private void btnAdaugaStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objStudenti = new Student();
            objStudenti.FirstName= textBoxFirstName.Text;
            objStudenti.LastName= textBoxLastName.Text;
            objStudenti.Grade= Convert.ToInt32(textBoxGrade.Text);
            if (objStudenti.Grade>= 4 
                   && objStudenti.Grade <= 10 
                   && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(objStudenti.FirstName) 
                   && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(objStudenti.LastName))
                listaStudenti.Add(objStudenti);
            MessageBox.Show(listaStudenti.Count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Storing a temporary value in a field is a very bad idea. It's all too easy to use the wrong value at the wrong place. That field means the last object value will remain in memory even after the method completes.

Comment: listaStudenti.Average(x => x.Grade)